# Android 2.x and 3.x WebKit mess

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm developing an Android app, and my intention is to be able to publish it for Android 2.2+ at least. Currently, I'm limited to Android 4.0+ because of the WebView control being a mess.
The app is largely HTML+CSS+JS+jQuery based.

`div.appList` shows a list of apps, and when clicked the app should launch. Only there's some trouble with this; For the list to be scrollable, I have to add `overflow: scroll;` to its parent. This works fine in Android 3.0+. In Android 2.x the list is still not scrollable.
I said it worked fine in Android 3.0? Well, the scrolling does. Now the problem is that it doesn't register clicks. If the user taps an item in the list, the click event simply doesn't get triggered, because, I'm guessing, it's registered as the user scrolling through the list. Making the list unscrollable again makes the items clickable, but then again, the list is useless because you can only access the top few items.

Everything works fine in Android 4.0+

**Any help would be hugely appreciated.**

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loadingScreen">
    </div>
    <div id="desktop">
        <div class="unity panel">
        </div>
        <div class="unity launcher">
            <div class="launcherIcon bfb">
                <img src="img/unity/launcher.bfb.png" alt="Dash Home" />
            </div>
            <div class="launcherApps iScroll" id="launcherApps">
            </div>
            <div class="launcherIcon launchTrash">
                <img src="img/apps/trash.icon.png" alt="Rubbish Bin" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="window">
            <div class="windowClose">
            </div>
            <div class="windowContent">
                <div class="windowPreferences">
                    <p>Nothing to be seen here, yet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="unity dash">
            <div class="dashContent">
                <div class="dashApps dashPage iScroll" id="dashApps">
                    <div class="appList"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="dashFiles dashPage iScroll" id="dashFiles">
                    <div class="fileList"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dashRibbon">
                <img src="img/unity/apps.png" alt="Applications" class="activeRibbonItem ribbonApps" />
                <!--<img src="img/unity/files.png" alt="Files" class="ribbonFiles" />-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
html, body
{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Droid Sans';
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(43,0,30);
}

/*# Loading screen #*/
div#loadingScreen
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(43,0,30) url(img/ubuntuLogo.png) center center no-repeat;
    color: white;
    z-index: 49;
}

/*# Desktop #*/
div#desktop
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgb(43,0,30) url(img/wallpaper/wartyFinal.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
div.unity.panel
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    background: rgb(69,68,64) url(img/unity/panel.background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
    div.unity.panel.dashOpened
    {
        background: transparent url(img/unity/dashOpened.png);
        border-bottom: 1px solid #504E4F;
    }
div.unity.launcher
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 0px; /* Animates to 64px */
    background: transparent url(img/unity/launcher.background.png);
    border-right: 1px solid #504E4F;
    padding: 3px 0px 55px 0px;
}
    div.unity.launcher.dashOpened
    {
        background: transparent url(img/unity/dashOpened.png);
    }
    div.launcherIcon
    {
        display: none;
        width: 52px;
        height: 52px;
        margin: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: transparent url(img/unity/launcher.iconbg.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
        div.unity.launcherIcon.dashOpened
        {
            background: grey !important;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        div.launcherIcon.bfb
        {
            background-image: none;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
            div.launcherIcon.bfb img
            {
                width: 52px;
                height: 52px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
        div.launcherIcon img
        {
            width: 46px;
            height: 46px;
            margin: 3px;
        }
        div.launcherIcon.launchFirefox
        {
            background-color: rgb(247,192,48);
        }
        div.launcherIcon.launchTrash
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 3px;
            background-color: #303030;
        }
    div.window
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 24px;
        left: 64px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background: rgb(242,241,239);
        color: black;
    }
        div.windowClose
        {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 64px;
            height: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            background: url(img/window/close.png) center center no-repeat;
        }
div.dash
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 64px;
    top: 24px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: transparent url(img/unity/dashOpened.png);
    padding: 0px 12px 48px 12px;
    color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
}
    div.dash.dashOpened
    {
        display: block;
    }
    div.dash *:link
    {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
    }
    div.dash ul li
    {
        padding: 5px;
    }

/*# Applications #*/
div.appWindow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var bootscreenDelay = 500; // 2500 //
var appOpened = false;
var dashOpened = false;

$(document).ready
(
    function ()
    {
        $('div#loadingScreen').delay (bootscreenDelay).fadeOut (800);
        $('div#desktop').delay (bootscreenDelay + 300).fadeIn (600,
            function ()
            {
                $('div.unity.panel').slideDown (400,
                    function ()
                    {
                        $('div.unity.launcher').css ('display', 'block').animate ( { width: 64 }, 600,
                            function ()
                            {
                                $('div.launcherIcon').each
                                (
                                    function (i)
                                    {
                                        $(this).delay (i * 200).slideDown (400);
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        $('div.windowClose').click
        (
            function ()
            {
                $('div.appFirefox .appFirefoxBrowser').fadeOut (400,
                    function ()
                    {
                        appFirefoxNavigate ('http://start.ubuntu.com/');
                    }
                );
                $('div.appWindow.appFirefox').fadeOut (800);
                $('div.window').delay (200).fadeOut (800);
                appOpened = false;
            }
        );

        /*# Dash #*/
        $('div.launcherIcon.bfb').click
        (
            function ()
            {
                if (! dashOpened)
                    openDash ();
                else
                    closeDash ();
            }
        );

        /*# Trash #*/
        $('div.launcherIcon.launchTrash').click
        (
            function ()
            {
                closeEverything ();

                android.openInBrowser ('http://www.dafk.net/what/');
            }
        );
    }
);

function closeEverything ()
{
    $('div.windowClose').trigger ('click');
    closeDash ();
}

function openDash ()
{
    $('*').addClass ('dashOpened');
    dashOpened = true;

    var appList = android.getApplicationList ();
    var pkgMan = android.getPackageManager ();
    var strAppList = '<ul>';
    for (var i = 0; i < appList.size (); i++)
    {
        var appLabel = android.getApplicationLabel (appList.get (i));
        strAppList += '<li onclick="launchApp (' + i + ')">' + appLabel + '</li>';
    }
    strAppList += '</ul>';
    $('div.appList').html (strAppList);
}

function closeDash ()
{
    $('*').removeClass ('dashOpened');
    dashOpened = false;
}

function launchApp (i)
{
    android.launchAppFromList (i);
}
```

---

Anything that helps me get it working on an older version is appreciated. The goal is Android 2.x, but if you can help me make it work on 3.2+, I'm already very happy.

Comment: Intra-page scrolling (that is, a scrolling element within the overall scrollable page) is simply a non-starter for old Android browsers. It's not supported at all.

Comment: @Pointy The page itself is not scrollable at all. The `div` inside it should be, though.

Comment: Well as far as I know, `overflow: auto` on anything but the overall page simply doesn't work on the old browser. Maybe somebody else knows better :-) (*edit* I mean `overflow: anything` involving scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:scroll|auto` dowsn't work properly on Android 2.X devices. 
This css rule equals to `overflow:hidden` :)

You can't fix it but you can use plugins to avoid this behaviour e.g. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Wow, that iScroll stuff really doesn't work for shit... I mean, it works fine with some simple stuff, but from the moment the page gets a little more complicated all you'll get out of it are script errors.

Comment: @RobinJ which errors? Can you also describe which content should be displayed on your page?

Comment: I managed to work around most problems, and .dashApps is now scrollable. However, I still fail to get the same done for .launcherApps.

Comment: I have no idea why this not working for you. You have to create new scroll when container is rendered and visible with one line: `new iScroll($('#launcherApps').get(0))`. Also this container should contain only one div ('viewport') and all content should be inside it. If my advice doesn't help you - please provide fiddle and I will help with it

Comment: Hmm, there are several items in the element I pointed iScroll at, so that might be one problem. The other problem is that the content of those elements are added and removed dynamically while the app is running.

Comment: Although the issue is not fixed yet, it has helped a bit. So I'm going to award the bounty to you, rather than letting it expire, because sooner or later I'll probably get the iScroll thing to work.... somehow.

Comment: @RobinJ take a look. I hope it will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/qHqnG/